# Illegal string offset PHP when getting data from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
if (strtotime($row['banned_until']) < time())
    {
        echo '<td>"Not currently banned"</td>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<td>'.$row['banned_until'].'</td>';
    }
    if (empty($row=''))
    {
        echo '<td>"Not currently banned"</td>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<td>'.$row['ban_reason'].'</td>';
    }
```

The above is my code. What I am trying to do is the code check with the database if banned_until is less than current time then print "Not currently banned" otherwise print the ban time. And the second part is check with the databse if the "ban_reason" is NULL print "Not currently banned" otherwise print the "ban_reason". The problem is for the user who has been banned it show the correct details of two columns but with a error message of Illegal string offset. And for those users who have not been banned they did not show "Not currently banned" it shows nothing. Anyone can help me with this?? Thank you very much. I am still new to phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Please post code as code, not as a picture. Having said that, your problem is probably that you are doing `strtotime($query['banned_until'])` when you meant `strtotime($row['banned_until'])`

Comment: Sorry i tried to put code at first place but it always show the error message then i post a picture. I tried again it works now.

Comment: That code is nothing like your original picture...

Comment: Also in your original picture you had `empty($reason='')` which will always be true.

Comment: i change the first parts works like you suggested, Thank you for that. So I should delete the empty in the second part?

Comment: You probably want `empty($row['ban_reason'])`

Comment: yes, it works. Thank you very much for your help. I know it's a silly mistake